# How to simplify the integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

If any integration is in form $$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$ it easily follows the $\tan^{-1}x$ but How to simplify if we have

$$\int \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}-\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$. The first fraction is the one in your first integral. For the second use integration by parts factoring it as $x\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}$.

Comment: See also: [Some method to solve $\int \frac{1}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{2}} dx$ and some doubts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170207)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f(\alpha)=\int\dfrac{dx}{\alpha+x^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt\alpha}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt\alpha}\right)$

You can recover the original integral by putting $\alpha=1$ later,

Now, differentiating both sides.

$f'(\alpha)=\int\dfrac{-dx}{(\alpha+x^2)^2}=\frac{-1}{2(\alpha)^{3/2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt\alpha}\right)+\frac{1}{(\alpha)^{1/2}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{\alpha}}\frac{-x}{2(\alpha)^{3/2}}$

$\int\dfrac{dx}{(\alpha+x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{2(\alpha)^{3/2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt\alpha}\right)+\frac{1}{(\alpha)^{1/2}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{\alpha}}\frac{x}{2(\alpha)^{3/2}}$

Put $\alpha=1$

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}x+\frac{1}{1+x^2}.\frac{x}{2}$$ and of course the remaining $C$

And there you have your integral found by differentiating only.^^

Comment: And in general you can easily form a recursive identity to easily find $n^{th}$ power as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since 
$$\left(\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right)'=\frac{2-(1+x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{2}{(1+x^2)^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
one has
$$2\int \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=\frac{x}{1+x^2}+\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \int\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=\frac{x}{2(1+x^2)}+\frac{\tan^{-1} x}{2}+C$$

Answer (score 2):

by using partial fraction 
$$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1)^2})$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{x}{(x^2+1)}))$$

Answer (score 1):

An idea that works for $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$ and for all other exponents $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$ is to get the base of the denominator in the numerator

$$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}-\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)}$$

The integral of the first term we know because it has a lower exponent and for the second we can write it as $$\frac{1}{2}x\frac{2x}{(1+x)^2}$$ and integrate by parts

$$\frac{1}{2}\int x\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{2}x\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}$$

which makes it boil down again to the integral with the smaller exponent, which we know.

Adding the two parts we get the answer $$\arctan(x)-\frac{1}{2}x\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}-\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x)=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x)-\frac{1}{2}x\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to substitute $x=\tan(\theta)$. Then it boils down to 
$$\int \cos^2\theta d\theta = \theta/2 + \sin(2\theta)/2 + C$$

Now use $$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) = \frac{2\tan(\theta)}{1+\tan^2(\theta)}$$
Now put $\theta=\tan^{-1}x$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach: Add them to your integral table...

$$ \int{\frac{a}{{(a^2+x^2)}^2}dx=}\ \left(\frac{1}{{2a}^2}\right)arctan(x/a)+\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right)\frac{x}{a^2+x^2}\ +C$$

set a = 1:

$$\int{\frac{1}{{(1+x^2)}^2}dx}=\frac{1}{2}\left(arctan(x)+\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right)+C$$

If you need to prove this yourself, you can obtain the result above  by taking the derivative of the following standard integral with *respect a*:

$$\int \frac{1}{a^{2}+x^{2}} dx = \frac{1}{a} arctan(x/a)$$