# How to find integrals of the form $\frac 1{(a^2+x^2)^n}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How will we find the integrals of the form $\frac 1{(a^2+x^2)^n}$? 
For example if we find the integral of $\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^3}$, I cannot see any substitution here. Moreover, if we do integration by parts, it becomes more and more messy. I have heard somewhere about reduction formula, so please can someone explain the derivation of it and why does it work?

Comment: The specific example can be done by putting $x=tan\theta$ and then it is class 12 trigonmetry by formulas like $cos2\theta = 2cos^2\theta -1$ etc.

Comment: No it is not. :).

Comment: Please show me that way then. Prove me wrong.

Comment: $cos^4\theta = (1+cos2\theta)^2$ . Then again use the same formula. Something like that. I did not wrote the constants. And it is always for that special case.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260469/how-to-simplify-the-integration/1260534#1260534 , here's a possible duplicate. @AdityaAgarwal :D

Comment: No I dont think so, they are poles apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let your integral be $I_n$. Then we use integral by part:

Let $\frac{1}{(a^2+x^2)^{n}} = u$, $du = \frac{-2nx}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}}dx$

$dx = dv, v = x$

$I_n  = \frac{x}{(a^2+x^2)^{n}} + \int \frac{2nx^2}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}}dx $

The integral on the RHS can be written as: $\int \frac{2n(x^2+a^2)}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}}dx - \int \frac{2na^2}{(a^2+x^2)^{n+1}}dx = 2nI_n-2na^2I_{n+1} $

Then: $I_n = \frac{x}{(a^2+x^2)^{n}} + 2nI_n-2na^2I_{n+1}$

Or: $I_{n+1} = \frac{x}{2na^2(a^2+x^2)^{n}} + \frac{2n-1}{2na^2}I_n$

From this recursive formula, you can calculate $I_n$ (It's gonna be very lengthy, so I won't write it explicitly here)

Comment: Very nice thought +1.

Comment: Yes, this was the question all about! There aint a shorter method?

Comment: So far, this is the only method that I know. However, personally I think it's elementary and already short.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a\not=0,$ then we know that$$\int_0^y\dfrac{1}{a^2+x^2}dx=\arctan \dfrac{y}{a}$$ Then you can use [differentiation under integration sign](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDifferentiation_under_the_integral_sign&ei=AEFxVcPbJsS3uQTH1oD4Cg&usg=AFQjCNFG_dT4I0_dXmaNcKoKaQkAq7jcAw) with respect to $a.$