# Question about integration by parts

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Could someone please explain how we calculated the first term of the second identity?

[image]

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Which term? The $\displaystyle \int \dfrac 1 {(x^2 + 1)^2} \, \mathrm dx$ term?

Comment: The term right after it. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35924/integral-of-frac11x22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integration by part with $f'(x)=1$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ yields 
$$
\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}\,dx 
=x\cdot\frac{1}{x^2+1}-\int x\cdot\frac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx\\
=\frac{x}{x^2+1}+2\int\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx\\
=\frac{x}{x^2+1}+2\int\frac{(x^2+1)-1}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx\\
=\frac{x}{x^2+1}+2\int\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}\right)\,dx\\
=\frac{x}{x^2+1}+2\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}\,dx-2\int\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx
$$

For the second equality set
$$
I=\int\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx\qquad
J=\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}\,dx
$$
In part 1 we proved that 
$$
J=\frac{x}{x^2+1}+2J-2I
$$
Hence 
$$
2I=\frac{x}{x^2+1}+J
$$
that is 
$$
I=\frac{x}{2(x^2+1)}+\frac{J}{2}
$$
as requared.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please add how we calculated the second equality? Thanks again!

Comment: I add the proof of part 2.

Comment: Thanks again! You helped me much.