# Finding legitimate pdf with joint pdf.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

Suppose $(X,Y)$ have joint pdf given by:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{c}{\left(1+\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)^2}$$

Find $c$ such that $f_{X,Y}$ is a legitimate pdf.

I know that $f_{X,Y}$ has to be positive or 0 given that $c \geq 0$. But I'm stuck on the integration to check what value of $c$ allows the pdf to equal 1.

I've tried setting $x = \arctan(u)$ with different values of $a$ to see if I can get a similar result as mentioned on the [Integral of $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35924/integral-of-frac11x22) but the $y^2$ component in the denominator is making things tricky when evaluating the first double integral with respect to $x$.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use polar coordinates to integrate

Comment: I think that works thank you!

Comment: You could first find either of the marginal densities from the joint density and  then find $c$ from the marginal, if that makes things easier. By the way, you haven't mentioned the support of the joint distribution.