# Indefinite integral through factorization

Tags: proof-explanation, indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration

So I have
$$\int \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$$

And the professor does some magic

[image]

I'm confused. what's with the derivative?
I solved the integral via substitution but I'm curious how this works, so I can learn it
thanks!

Comment: If you used substitution you likely made a mistake.  Can you share your work?

Comment: The technique here is called [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of rational functions.  That's a “standard” bit of magic, and google will produce hundreds of videos explaining it.  The author is choosing the form of the decomposition judiciously to make the integration as quick as possible, which is somewhat more advanced magic.

Comment: this is how I did it. it may be wrong but I could not come up with a better solution http://imgur.com/gallery/M5krcpJ

Comment: Ah, so that seems to work after all! When you said substitution I thought maybe you used $u=x^2+1$ and $du = 2x$.  That, of course, doesn't work.  But I hadn't expected the trig substitution $u=\tan x$ producing an answer like that.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35924/integral-of-frac11x22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you differentiate $\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+1}$, then you get the quatioent of a second degree polynomial with $(x^2+1)^2$. If you add to it $\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+1}$, then you get the quotient of a cubic polynomial by $(x^2+1)^2$. So, it is reasonable to expect that you can express $\frac1{(x^2+1)^2}$ as such an expression. On the other hand,$$\int\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx=\frac A2\log(x^2+1)+B\arctan(x),$$and therefore this allows you to obtain$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac A2\log(x^2+1)+B\arctan(x)+\frac{Cs+D}{x^2+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I had not been given the tools to solve it in class, so I'll have to read up on this on my own

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to shorten this magic as follows

\begin{eqnarray*} \int \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}dx
& = & \int \frac{1+x^2 - x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}dx \\
& = & \int \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx - \frac{1}{2}\int x\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx \\
& = & \arctan x - \frac{1}{2}\left(- \frac{x}{x^2+1} + \int \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx\right) \\
& = & \arctan x + \frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{x^2+1} - \frac{1}{2}\arctan x \;(+C) \\
& = & \frac{1}{2}\left(\arctan x + \frac{x}{x^2+1}\right) \;(+C) \\
\end{eqnarray*}